# How to get the signer's company name from a memory signed file data?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I use the `CryptQueryObject` function to get `HCRYPTMSG* phMsg`.

The `dwObjectType` is `CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_BLOB` and the `pvObject` is a `CERT_BLOB` (set the memory data point and size) pointer. It can work in windows7, but has problem in Vista. In Vista, it will return error code `0x80092009` ("cannot find the requested object").

Any suggestions?  Thanks all.